# SharePoint 2010 Metadata Navigation Heirarchy not Filtering

Tags: 2010, managed-metadata

I have four colunms on my document library as metadata tags - `Certificates, staff, Region, & language.`

I have added all four to my metadata navigational hierarchy.

**Problem:**

I can only filter by certificates, region, & staff. When I try to filter by Language, the filter returns zero(0) documents, but I have tagged some documents with Language metadata tag.

Any idea why is these happening?

Comment: Due to the number of characters allowed, I am unable to supply more information on the issue but you can follow the following link. 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/5077a9f6-2183-4600-b02a-667b9f8684a9

Thank you.

Comment: Have you run a Crawl on your documents since adding the columns?  Are the Metadata Properties being populated after a crawl?  We found that unless the property is populated, and or mapped, it was not usable as a Filter later on.

Comment: We have the same problem, and have been working with Microsoft using a gold support case for the last 2 months. It is not so easy for MS to reproduce, but hopefully once they are able to reproduce it, they'll be able to determine why this happens, and issue a fix. I will keep you updated.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys.
We really battling on this one.